# What is Steam rating and what does it do?

Tags: steam

I just noticed that apparently Steam has a rating and mine is 0.6:

[image: screenshot]

0.6 what? Is that good? Bad? Should I be forever embarrassed for having posted a screenshot?

Comment: FOREVER EMBARRASSED.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Your Steam rating relates to the amount of hours played in the last two weeks. It ranges from 0 if you haven't played at all right way up to 10 if you've played more than 32 hours.

Here's a table that explains hows is calculated and the titles of your rating (which is no longer displayed for some reason) from [Steam](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_rating).

```
    r = 10   EAGLES SCREAM!             h ≥ 32.0
9 ≤ r < 10   Still not 10        28.8 ≤ h < 32.0
8 ≤ r < 9    COBRA KAI!          25.6 ≤ h < 28.8
7 ≤ r < 8    Wax on, Wax off     22.4 ≤ h < 25.6
6 ≤ r < 7    Oooh! Shiny!        19.2 ≤ h < 22.4
5 ≤ r < 6    Halfway Cool        16.0 ≤ h < 19.2
4 ≤ r < 5    Master of Nothing   12.8 ≤ h < 16.0
3 ≤ r < 4    Shooting Blanks      9.6 ≤ h < 12.8
2 ≤ r < 3    Nearly Lifeless      6.4 ≤ h < 9.6
1 ≤ r < 2    El Terrible!         3.2 ≤ h < 6.4
0 ≤ r < 1    Teh Suck             0.0 ≤ h < 3.2
```

If I'm using the table correctly I think your Steam rating has the title "**Teh Suck**"...

Comment: If steam is going to tell me that I suck, I can totally understand why they took that away. It's quite insulting to casual gamers...

Comment: @Farseeker Or to those of us who play on multiple platforms (or both! :)).

Comment: they should rename it to addict-o-meter (while increasing the upper bound to something closer to 24/7)